# can i desearlize json data into a static class

Tags: c#

So what i wanted to do is bring json data into a static class.
but my current method as shown is to have 2 classes, one to get the data and then another static class, the same, to hold the data

the goal here is to have the static class of data

```
internal class _iData
{       
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Shelf { get; set; }
    public string Quantiy { get; set; }
}

public static class ItemData 
{
    public static string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public static string UserName { get; set; }
    public static string Description { get; set; }
    public static string Shelf { get; set; }
    public static string Quantiy { get; set; }
}

_iData ob = js.Deserialize<_iData>(objText);
// Move data from instantiated class to static class
ItemData.CompanyName = ob.CompanyName;
ItemData.Description = ob.Description;
ItemData.Quantiy = ob.Quantiy;
ItemData.Shelf = ob.Shelf;
ItemData.UserName = ob.UserName;
```

i then have copy the data accross which isnt the end of the world but i feel im missing something

Comment: What's your problem here?

Comment: Did you write the deserializer yourself?

Comment: sorry i tried to keep it simple by removing some parts

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var objText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    _iData ob = js.Deserialize<_iData>(objText);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't deserialize to `static`.

When deserializing, you are getting an *instance*. `static` classes can't have instance (because they are `static`)

Comment: nothing prevents you from deserializing to static, it just not supported by most json deserializers

Answer (score 1):

```
internal class _iData
{       
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Shelf { get; set; }
    public string Quantiy { get; set; }
}

internal static class DataProvider 
{
    private static _iData _data;
    public static _iData ItemData { get {return DataProvider._data;} }

    public static void Deserialize(string json) 
    {
        DataProvider._data =js.Deserialize<_iData>(objText)
    }
}

DataProvider.Deserialize(objText);
```

Comment: Be careful, `public static _iData ItemData` is more accessible than `_iData`, and there is no `this` for static

Comment: No worries. `objText` should be json in the method (and `js` isn't defined)

Comment: I don't know what the serializer was used and use 'js' as an abstract serializer which is already defined